# What is the appropriate code structure in F# when you need to keep data around?

Tags: f#

I have now about 10 full days of experience with F#. I am porting one of our C# libraries both as practice but also because it really needed a rewrite.

The library is a utility library that connects to a socket, processes the incoming data and allows queries. The library maintains a state which is regularly updated through the socket events.

I have read (everywhere) that in functional languages, classes are not really appropriate and I should pass things I need from one call to the next.

However, in the case of a library like this, there are things that have to stay in place and be available as needed.

One example is the socket handle itself, and also the state of the data that has been processed.

This is an example of code which lends itself very well to object oriented design, but it seems to go against some of the F# principles I read.

So, in the F# world:
 - Is it accepted that some objects have to be stored, accessible globally and partially mutated? I can't recreate 10kb of data because 2 bytes changed. And the socket messages tell me what fields to change, what objects to add / update / delete from lists.
 - Is there a common accepted way, state based code is structured?

Currently I have made a master class that contains sub-classes; each of them processing a category of messages. This is a very OO design, but that's the world I come from.

With F# constructs and with the lack of partial classes, I felt like it was the ideal way to break down something large in small components.
The library is dealing with stock trading, so to give an example, the class hierarchy is like:

```
MasterClass
-> State of our portfolio (A)
-> Socket handling (B)
-> Processing currency changes class, called by events from B, updating A 
-> Processing trades changes class, called by events from B, updating A 
-> Processing order changes class, called by events from B, updating A 
... etc
```

Is there a more 'F#' way to do this?

To clarify and make sure this question doesn't get arbitrarily closed: I'm specifically looking for F# examples, or guidelines, that allow to implement the kind of system described above in a 'F#' way, because right now, I'm still thinking OO and I can't find resources showing how to structure something complex in F#. Small examples, yes, lots of them, but a complex real-world use case, I haven't found so far.

---

Edit:
Here is some clarification about how the code is used:

It is a library used to track the state of our accounts, as well as market situation, on a trading platform.

The code receives 7 categories of messages, through sockets, from the platform. Each message category has its own content, format, etc as they deal with different aspects of the state (positions held, last transactions, open orders, etc).
All messages are sent in full, to get the full state, upon connection, and then only deltas for each message as size / speed is critical; there is rarely more than 10 messages per second.

In the C# code, each message type has its own handler with its own class and own state object. The different message types do not share anything and have very different structures. The code receiving the socket messages parses the type and dispatches the message to the right handler.

The states are kept in ram and important data is pushed to InfluxDB for visualization.

One a message is decoded, an event is triggered to alert any listener.

So essentially, I'm trying to replicate 7 classes that get / parse a message, apply delta update to their state and alert a listener. Each of these classes is also performing some calculations, etc and they are roughly 5-6 pages of C# code each.

My question is if I should keep a similar structure in F# where one large object (the socket listener) has 7 classes that each handle a message type, have mutable storage because a delta update can sometimes be tiny, or is there any language construct that would allow me to make one large object, spread on several files; possibly this would mean less code and yet retain readability, but I'm not sure how this is typically done in F#.

Comment: "I have read (everywhere) that in functional languages, classes are not really appropriate and I should pass things I need from one call to the next." Can you cite the sources? Sounds like BS. From my experience, classes and functional programming live perfectly fine together.

Comment: It was from some random browsing of blogs (and medium.com posts) of people that switched to F#. I can look up the history when back at the office; but overall what I was reading seemed to go, from my newbie understanding, in the direction that not only all data objects have to be constantly re-created (vs. modified) and that, when calling methods, all that's needed has to be passed vs. the method pulling data and combining it with the parameters. Sorry it's a bit vague, it's because I read a lot of random thing and this created that image in my mind.

Comment: All these pure functional ideas are great to follow, but only until they got in your way. "all that's needed has to be passed vs. the method pulling data" sounds great (e.g. it facilitates testing), but then you find out that you need to pass 15 parameters to a function (I've seen this) or encounter the situation like yours. All this immutability is great, but it has 2 concerns. 1) GC, which has to do much more work; but in reasonable scenarios it's OK. 2) Large objects; you don't want to recreate them each time. My point is that if you can't write something in FP, then maybe you shouldn't.

Comment: this type of transformation lends itself well for FP, just use you functions to update your data, in a pipeline. you don't need all those classes. You don't need global state either but might need to encapsulate the state in some sort of object/class, that's fine. If you find that performance is not acceptable you can even mutate. I think the OO structure you mention is really convoluted.

Comment: the structure is a bit heavy because each module doing processing work is a bunch of pages of code and they're dealing with specific messages; for readability, I can't have it all in one place. Now in C# I can do a single class with multiple files and partial class definitions. I guess in F#, since there is no direct equivalent, I could maybe split the code in various modules, all called from the dispatcher. That would allow to fit everything in one class.

Comment: yes, luckily F# doesn't do partial classes. You can still use a common namespace (ok to use multiple files) for your modules if they span multiple files. just use function signatures and interfaces for common operations. I don't see an issue dumping everything into one file either btw.

Comment: I feel people will be able to answer more easily if you define more specifically what you're trying to achieve. You haven't said whether you're storing on disk or in memory for example. Modules with multiple smaller record types could be one answer to this question, but it's hard to tell. I wonder whether looking in to resources about `elmish` or `event sourcing` might help you formulate ideas about ways to functional approaches to managing state?

Comment: I just added details on how the system works and narrowed the question down.

Comment: I believe I can give advice, but this is two months old now, and I'm not sure it's relevant to you any more. Also, I think it's easier to keep a conversation going on e.g. fsharp.slack.com, while an answer here would at best be a starting point.

Comment: @BentTranberg, I've learned a lot more since then, but an answer would be welcome since I still have some fuzzy areas when it comes to f#